# WPF: Expression with joined DataBinding and value

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In the customized Slider template I've got, the main border's Height is bound to the **TemplateBinding Height** property, I want the Thumb element's height value to be higher by 2-3 pixels relatively to the **TemplateBinding Height** property I stated before.
Is there any elegant way to achieve that without getting ValueConverters and AttachedProperties involved? 
Something like

`Height="{TemplateBinding Height} + 3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Options:

1) Consider setting the margin of your control whose Height is bound to -3.  I think this will satisfy your description of "higher by 2-3 pixels".  If not -3, you can play with other margin values.

2) If 1 doesn't work, then you'll need to write an `IValueConverter` class and set it as the converter for your binding.  Unfortunately, TemplateBinding doesn't support converters since they are meant to be lightweight connections to your Control's forward-facing properties.

Your binding will instead be:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource ReferenceToMyPlus3Converter}}"
```

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) to an example of writing a converter.

Comment: The 1st option is the best work-around for my case. Should have thought of it myself, thank you!